# Safecracker with JSON and MX Notify

Tags: safecracker, notification, json

I am having a bit of a issue when it comes to using MXNotify module and submitting a form with safecracker.

What's happening is if all fields are correct, it will save the post, and send the email, but it breaks my javascript submit, as it does a 302 redirect, and doesn't respond with the JSON my submit function is expecting. Therefore I can't use ajax to show the success. Are there any ways to still get my custom email sent on updating this channel, and still get a JSON response on success?

If this helps:

> {exp:safecracker channel="deal_registration"
>   return="deal-registration" error_handling="inline" json="yes"
>   include_jquery="no" class="registration-form" safecracker_head="no"}

The URL is site.com/deal-registration and it posts back to it self to show the AJAX responses.

Comment: If you disable MX Notify, does it work properly?

Comment: yes it does.. that's why I know it's the issue. I just need it to send customized auto responders. But if postmaster does the job and doesn't interfere with the use of inserting a record via safecracker then I'll use that..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that familiar with MX Notify, but I can't imagine why it's impacting the response given.

You might try using Objective HTML's [Postmaster](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster) instead. Being a commercial add-on it'll offer better support should you have any problems with it.

Comment: MX Notify, listens for changes. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-notify-control. So for what I am doing.. If it's successful it gets a 302 and the data coming back is not in the format it needs to be. So it adds the record and sends the email, but I can't clean up the front end. If I use the return parameter, I don't think that will work on error.

Comment: Seems postmaster doesn't let me send a new registered user from the CP their login credentials, at-least the live preview isn't parsing the variables MX did. sigh :(

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions in regards to getting Postmaster setup. Email support@objectivehtml for details, and I am happy to get you pointed in the right direction.